# Eclipse/CDT cannot debug application with linked dependencies - program exits with code 0xc0000135

Tags: c++, eclipse, dll, eclipse-cdt

I have two C++ projects in Eclipse, "amp" and "amp_auditions"

The first creates a library, `C:\Users\Jared\EclipseWorkspace\amp\Debug\libamp.dll`

The second, a test program (`'C:\Users\Jared\EclipseWorkspace\amp_auditions'`), depends on the first, and has the directory `C:\Users\Jared\EclipseWorkspace\amp\Debug` listed under Project Properties > Library Dependencies

To use the amp library I created, I thought all I needed to do was link the library file and include the headers, but apparently it isn't that simple.

Everything compiles, but when I go to debug, the application immediately terminates.  The GDB trace tells me:

```
488,262 19^error,msg="During startup program exited with code 0xc0000135."
```

*If I run the test program directly in a terminal*, it complains about missing dependencies.  **If I place the `libamp.dll` file in the `C:\Users\Jared\EclipseWorkspace\amp_auditions` directory, everything works just fine.  This tells me it is an issue where the debugger can't find `libamp.dll`**

What did I miss?  Why won't my test program run within the Eclipse debug perspective?

gcc -v

```
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: mingw32
Configured with: ../gcc-4.6.2/configure --enable-languages=c,c++,ada,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --disable-sjlj-exceptions --with-dwarf2 --enable-shared --enable-libgomp --disable-win32-registry --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --build=mingw32 --prefix=/mingw
Thread model: win32
gcc version 4.6.2 (GCC)
```

gdb trace:

```
487,988 2-environment-cd C:/Users/Jared/EclipseWorkspace/amp_auditions
487,991 2^done
487,991 (gdb) 
487,991 3-gdb-set breakpoint pending on
487,991 3^done
487,991 (gdb) 
487,992 4-gdb-set detach-on-fork on
487,992 4^done
487,992 (gdb) 
487,992 5-enable-pretty-printing
487,992 5^done
487,992 (gdb) 
487,992 6-gdb-set python print-stack none
487,993 6^done
487,993 (gdb) 
487,993 7-gdb-set print object on
488,003 7^done
488,003 (gdb) 
488,004 8-gdb-set print sevenbit-strings on
488,005 8^done
488,005 (gdb) 
488,005 9-gdb-set host-charset UTF-8
488,005 9^done
488,006 (gdb) 
488,006 10-gdb-set target-charset WINDOWS-1252
488,016 10^done
488,016 (gdb) 
488,017 11-gdb-set target-wide-charset UTF-16
488,017 11^done
488,017 (gdb) 
488,017 12source .gdbinit
488,027 &"source .gdbinit\n"
488,027 &".gdbinit: No such file or directory.\n"
488,027 12^error,msg=".gdbinit: No such file or directory."
488,027 (gdb) 
488,028 13-gdb-set target-async off
488,028 13^done
488,028 (gdb) 
488,029 14-gdb-set auto-solib-add on
488,029 14^done
488,029 (gdb) 
488,029 15-gdb-set solib-search-path C:\\Users\\Jared\\EclipseWorkspace\\amp\\Debug
488,029 15^done
488,029 (gdb) 
488,031 16-file-exec-and-symbols --thread-group i1 C:/Users/Jared/EclipseWorkspace/amp_auditions/Deb\
ug/amp_auditions.exe
488,065 16^done
488,065 (gdb) 
488,067 17-break-insert --thread-group i1 -t -f main
488,134 18-list-thread-groups
488,167 17^done,bkpt={number="1",type="breakpoint",disp="del",enabled="y",addr="0x004013ad",func="ma\
in()",file="..\\src\\amp_auditions.cpp",fullname="C:\\Users\\Jared\\EclipseWorkspace\\amp_auditions\\
\src\\amp_auditions.cpp",line="14",times="0",original-location="main"}
488,167 (gdb) 
488,167 18^done,groups=[{id="i1",type="process",executable="C:\\Users\\Jared\\EclipseWorkspace\\amp_\
auditions\\Debug\\amp_auditions.exe"}]
488,168 (gdb) 
488,172 19-exec-run --thread-group i1
488,205 =thread-group-started,id="i1",pid="3220"
488,205 =thread-created,id="1",group-id="i1"
488,205 ~"[New Thread 3220.0xa8c]\n"
488,205 19^running
488,205 *running,thread-id="all"
488,205 (gdb) 
488,206 20-list-thread-groups --available
488,260 =thread-exited,id="1",group-id="i1"
488,261 =thread-group-exited,id="i1"
488,262 19^error,msg="During startup program exited with code 0xc0000135."
488,262 (gdb) 
488,262 20^error,msg="Can not fetch data now."
488,263 (gdb) 
488,270 21-gdb-exit
488,293 21^exit
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My understanding of the problem is that this has nothing to do with eclipse. A .dll is linked dynamically, at runtime. This means that your running application must find the library (.dll) in the system path or in the running executable folder.

A solution to your immediate problem would be to add the directory where the .dll is compiled to your Windows path variable.

Comment: I just found out: YES it HAS to do with eclipse. Starting somewhere between Windows 7 and 10 Microsoft decided to rename PATH to Path. So when you try to run the executable, eclipse will append ${CYGWIN_HOME}/bin to the PATH variable. However due to the renaming above, we now have two variables (one PATH which will be ignored and one Path which will be used). Since the required dll's will be in the cygwin/bin dir -> you won't find it.

Comment: Workarounds: Start eclipse from cygwin console or add the cygwin/bin path to the windows path...

Answer (score 1):

You build your test application and DLL to different folders. There's no way EXE will know where DLL is. The typical solutions are:

1. Build to the same folder, such as 'Bin'
2. Copy the DLL as a post-build step.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to add the paths to your dlls to the **LD_LIBRARY_PATH**
In the debug configuration in Eclipse (Right click your project, debug as, debug configuration) click on the Environment tab. Click the New... button and put

```
Name:  LD_LIBRARY_PATH
Value: put the absolute path to your dll here. Separate multiple paths with a ";"
```

On Mac OS X its called **DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH**
On Linux based system you can define the variable temporarily in the same command like this:

```
bash$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/libs ./executable
```

I'm not sure how to do this in windows. 
Double check to see if the path to your libraries is correct!

Answer (score 1):

Another easy option is to configure the Run->Debug Configurations in eclipse:
There, expand the C/C++ Application, select your Debug application, then in the right-hand "Debugger" tab click on the "Shared Libraries" tab and add the paths to your shared libraries.

Answer (score 1):

For other looking for a solution:

The run configuration allows you set a PATH. Here you can add your own settings without modifying the system environment (yet).
I tend to forget this at times and run into the exact same problem you described. Adding the path here solves the issue.